# ¿Como hacer un explode a un string sin espacios especificos en PHP?

Tags: php, php7, explode

tengo un gran inconveniente el cual llevo mucho tiempo intentando resolver y aun no puedo, yo desde mi base de datos recibo un campo tipo `string` el cual viene formado de la siguiente manera:

```
FAMILIAR: NIEGA PATOLOGICO: NIEGA NEONATAL: EMBARAZO NORMAL PERSONALES: NO REFIERE
```

Lo que intento lograr tal cual como esta mencionado anteriormente es convertir a un arreglo entre indice y valor, es decir, *que lo que esta antes de los puntos seria mi indice y despues de los puntos el valor* **eje:**

```
[
 [FAMILIAR, NIEGA],
 [PATOLOGICO, NIEGA],
 [NEONATAL, EMBARAZO NORMAL],
 [PERSONALES, NO REFIERE]
]
```

Es como la idea pero si hay una forma mucho mejor agradecería de gran manera el interés.

Comment: Saludos. Me parece será más un proceso lo que necesitas que un simple (uso de la instrucción) `explode`. De ser posible si puedes modificar la cadena que recibes para agregarle un caracter de uso poco frecuente (digamos) como el `~` y este sea tu primer delimitador y luego el `:` con c/u de estos un `explode` obtener lo que deseas.

Comment: Hola @RobertoLeOr, gracias por tu interes y si, correcto, tienes toda la razón, el problema es que no hay ninguna forma de poner ese dilimitador ya que eso internamente es informacion que nosotros no manipulamos sino que consumimos y que lastimosamente la calidad de la informacion que estamos recibiendo como lo vez es supremamente pesima y eso que es la forma mas ordenada que hay porque llega muchisimo peor.

Comment: Lo tienes complicado con expresiones regulares también, porque el caracter delimitador es el espacio, pero tambien se utiliza el espacio para algunos valores como "EMBARAZO NORMAL". Dices que recibís los datos de una forma peor, ¿Podrías añadirla de todas formas para ver si se puede hacer algo con ello?

Comment: Yo pienso que esto se deberia solucionar desde la raiz, porque simplemente no se recibe "EMBARAZO NORMAL". Ya que lo otro que quieres hacer lo considero inefeciente por este motivo. Si tubieras dicha funcion que pone explode sin espacios especificos, tendrias que ir limitando "todos" los espacios que quieras, ya se por tu ejemplo "EMBARAZO NOMRLA PERSONALES" u otros textos que tienen espacios. Yo siempre pienso si se hace una funcion, se deberia hacer para cualquier caso, y si tu string vienen mas de 1000 palabras con espacios, tendrias que limitar los 1000

Comment: Hola @ordago, claro que podria, pero podria complicar mas el escenario y no quiero, te puedo poner un ejemplo de un medicamento: SULFATO+PIRIMETAMINA, aqui no hay indice, solo un valor algo que no me serviria y que tendria que descartar,  entonces son muchisimas variables o condiciones o casos tambien que pueden ocurrir ero el ejemplo que doy es el mas "limpio" que puede haber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el espacio puede estar en 3 posiciones distintas:

- Después del separador de clave-valor `:`
- Como separador de pares clave-valor
- Dentro de los valores

La idea es *normalizar* la cadena para distinguir los casos.
Usando una expresión regular para ignorar el espacio después de `:` y marcando/reemplazando los espacios en valores conocidos:

```
define('cReemplazo','+'); // Caracter de Reemplazo
$cadena = 'FAMILIAR: NIEGA PATOLOGICO: NIEGA NEONATAL: EMBARAZO NORMAL PERSONALES: NO REFIERE';

$valoresConEspacio = ['EMBARAZO NORMAL','NO REFIERE'];
foreach( $valoresConEspacio as $v )
   $cadena = str_replace($v, str_replace(' ', cReemplazo, $v), $cadena);

$resultado = [];
preg_match_all( '/(\w+?): ([A-Z'.cReemplazo.']+)/', $cadena, $matches );
foreach($matches[1] as $i => $clave)
   $resultado[$clave] = str_replace(cReemplazo, ' ', $matches[2][$i]);
var_dump($resultado);
```

Da como resultado:

```
array(4) {
  ["FAMILIAR"]=>
  string(5) "NIEGA"
  ["PATOLOGICO"]=>
  string(5) "NIEGA"
  ["NEONATAL"]=>
  string(15) "EMBARAZO NORMAL"
  ["PERSONALES"]=>
  string(10) "NO REFIERE"
}
```

Si incluyes en la normalización el reemplazo de `:`  por `:` podrías hacer dos `explode`: uno con   y otro con `:` en lugar de usar la expresión regular.

La idea de parsear por `:` me parece buena, una forma mas simple sería:

```
$cadena = 'FAMILIAR: NIEGA PATOLOGICO: NIEGA NEONATAL: EMBARAZO NORMAL PERSONALES: NO REFIERE';

$resultado = [];  
foreach( explode(' ',$cadena) as $pedazo )
    if( substr($pedazo, -1) === ':' ){
        $clave = substr($pedazo, 0, -1);
        $resultado[$clave] = '';
    }else{
        $resultado[$clave] .= ($resultado[$clave] === '' ? '' : ' ').$pedazo;
    }
var_dump($resultado);
```

Comment: Mil y mil gracias por tu ayuda y la forma de explicarme como hacerlo, nunca crei que me fuera a dar tan duro trata de resolver algo que se ve facil, pero me vencio y no encontre otra alternativa que buscar aqui en la comunidad, ambas formas son lo maximo, cumplen tal cual el objetivo y se pudo sacar adelante el desarrollo que me tenia frustado gracias a ti y a los demas compañeros que ahn contribuido para resolver el problema que presentaba. un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero realizar los siguientes pasos:

*A continuación llamare `$cadena` al *string* que recibes.*

1. Crear variables `$resultado` y `$grupo` *(sea un array)* e inicializarlas en vació.
2. Almacenar en (digamos variable) `$sinDoblesPuntos` el resultado de `explode(':', $cadena)`.

> Considero *(asumo)* que cada elemento `$sinDoblesPuntos` no tiene espacios en los extremos.

3. El primer elemento de `$sinDoblesPuntos` agregarlo a `$grupo`.
4. Del elemento 2 en adelante (excepto el último) en un ciclo crear `$sinEspacios` y asignarle resultado de `explode(' ', $sinDoblesPuntos[$i++])`.

> `$i` empezaría en 1. En caso `$i` refiera el último elemento tomar directo el valor y agregarlo a `$grupo`.

5. De `$sinEspacios` tomar del primer elemento al penúltimo y agregarlo a `$grupo`.
6. Agregar `$grupo` a `$resultado`.
7. Vaciar `$grupo` y tomar el último elemento de `$sinEspacios` y agregarlo a `$grupo`.
8. Repetir desde el punto 4 hasta el final.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Con lo anterior lo que se busca es que de cada punto buscar el primer espacio hacia atrás y con ello lograr,

para el caso **NEONATAL: EMBARAZO NORMAL PERSONALES: NO REFIERE**

`[NEONATAL, EMBARAZO NORMAL], [PERSONALES, NO REFIERE]`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta roberto, me la complicaste un poco intentando de seguir la indicacion pero de eso se trata, no de hacer el trabajo (aunque es de muchisima ayuda), sino que se trata tambien de intentarlo y hecharle logica para sacar adelante el desarrollo

Answer (score 1):

En esta alternativa, primero se separan todas las palabras. Luego se recorre en array resultante buscando palabras que terminan en `':'`. Cuando encuentra uno, lo asigna como **índice** y su **valor** se asigna a `''`. En caso contrario, la palabra se va sumando al **valor**.

```
<?php
$str = "FAMILIAR: NIEGA PATOLOGICO: NIEGA NEONATAL: EMBARAZO NORMAL PERSONALES: NO REFIERE";
$partes = explode(' ', $str);
$result = array();
$idx = '';
foreach($partes as $palabra) {
    if(substr($palabra, -1) == ':') {
        $idx = substr($palabra, 0, -1);
        $result[$idx] = '';
        $i = 0; // Bandera - Agregar separador, excepto a la primera palabra
    } elseif($idx != '') {
        $result[$idx] .= (++$i > 1) ? ' '.$palabra : $palabra;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Salida:

```
array(4) {
  ["FAMILIAR"]=>"NIEGA"
  ["PATOLOGICO"]=>"NIEGA"
  ["NEONATAL"]=>"EMBARAZO NORMAL"
  ["PERSONALES"]=>"NO REFIERE"
}
```

Comment: Genial tu respuesta,  infinitas gracias por el interes y la ganas de poder ayudarme, lo he implementado y funciona tal cual lo que necestio, teniendo algo asi le puedo dar mas forma, un saludo